# What does a >> mean in Go language?

Tags: programming-languages, go, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I’m looking for information on Google’s Go language. In “A Tour of Go” they have this code:

```
const (
    Big = 1<<100
    Small = Big>>99
)
```

But what do `<<` and `>>`  mean?

You can see all of the code at http://tour.golang.org/#14

Comment: those are the `<<` left and `>>` right shift operators.

Comment: I'd imagine bit-shift like it does in (most?) C-like languages

Answer (score 37, accepted):

They are [bitwise shift operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts). `x << y` means *x* × 2<sup>*y*</sup>, while `x >> y` means *x* × 2<sup>*−y*</sup> or, equivalently, x ÷ 2<sup>y</sup>. These operators are generally used to manipulate the binary representation of a value, where, just like with a power of 10 in decimal, multiplying or dividing by a power of two has the effect of “shifting” the digits left or right, respectively:

```
// Left shift:

  13 *  2 ==    26 // decimal
1101 * 10 == 11010 // binary (13 is 8 + 4 + 0 + 1)

// Right shift (brackets denote discarded portion):

  13 /  2 ==   6[.5] // decimal
1101 / 10 == 110[.1] // binary
```

Because you are operating on integers and a right shift typically results in fractional values, there are a couple of ways to handle how the result of a right shift is rounded. In Go, right shift is a [logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) on unsigned values and an [arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) on signed values. Logical shift always rounds toward zero, while arithmetic shift always rounds down, that is, toward −∞.

Answer (score 7):

From the [specification](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Operators_and_Delimiters):

```
Arithmetic operators

...

<<   left shift             integer << unsigned integer
>>   right shift            integer >> unsigned integer
```

and a bit below:

> The shift operators shift the left operand by the shift count specified by the right operand. They implement arithmetic shifts if the left operand is a signed integer and logical shifts if it is an unsigned integer. There is no upper limit on the shift count. Shifts behave as if the left operand is shifted n times by 1 for a shift count of n. As a result, x << 1 is the same as x*2 and x >> 1 is the same as x/2 but truncated towards negative infinity.

Answer (score 6):

These are **bit shift left** and **bit shift right** operators.  They are the same as in the C language and it's derivatives.

```
x << y
```

is x times 2 to the power of y

```
x >> y
```

is x divided by 2 to the power of y (fractional part discarded)

If you view the numbers as binary, than multiplication by a power of 2 shifts the bits to the left (101 * 2^3 becomes 101000) in the same way as in decimal multiplying by powers of 10 shift the number to the left (12340 * 10^3 becomes 12340000).  The converse is true for division by powers of 2.  It shifts the binary representation to the right.  Hence the name.  This is an extremely fast operation for a computer to perform by the way, so it is used a lot in performance critical bit twiddling applications like cryptography for example.

Answer (score 4):

`<<` and `>>` are [shift operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_shift#Bit_shifts).

They work on the underlying binary representation of a number, and 'shift' the number left of the operator left or right by the amount of bits specified on the right of the operator:

```
1 << 1 == 2
2 << 1 == 4
111b << 3 == 111000b
```