# Tour of Go exercise #17: double less operator

Tags: go

In the Go Tour exercise [#17](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/17), I don't understand this expression `1 << uint(i)`

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    pow := make([]int, 10)
    for i := range pow {

        pow[i] = 1 << uint(i)
    }
    for _, value := range pow {
        fmt.Printf("%d\n", value)
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of this operator ? `<<`

The program outputs:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512

Program exited.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5801008/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/9797431/6309

Comment: When in doubt, read the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a binary shift operator. Specifically, its a left shift (since they point to the left).

What it does, is move all bits in the binary representation of a number ... left.

For example. The binary representation of 1 is (with a safe assumption of 8 bits per byte): `00000001`. Applying a left shift produces:

```
00000001
<<
00000010
```

Which is the binary representation of 2. Applying it again produces:

```
00000010
<<
00000100
```

..which is the binary representation of 4.. and so on.

Conversely, a right shift `>>` does the opposite, so applying `>>` to the value 4, produces:

```
00000100
>>
00000010
```

..2.

You can change the tour to count backwards by using the right shift operator:

```
pow[i] = 512 >> uint(i)
```